# Zooming an image drawn on a CGContext from the pinch location

Tags: objective-c, zooming, cgcontext

This question is a follow-up from another SO question from a while back: [zooming using pinch but not using transform methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10532113/zooming-using-pinch-but-not-using-transform-methods). I got the zooming to work pretty near perfectly, however it will still make the drawn image 'jump around' as I've been calling it. The most important parts of the code are the following:

When a pinch event is observed this method is called:

[code snippet 1]

```
- (IBAction)handlePinchGesture:(UIGestureRecognizer *)sender {
    float previousZoomLevel = zoomLevel;
    UIPinchGestureRecognizer *pinch = (UIPinchGestureRecognizer *)sender;

    float zoomIncreaseFactor = [self getZoomFactor:[pinch scale]]; //= 13 or 7 or 10
    float estimatedDelta = (previousZoomLevel * zoomIncreaseFactor) / 150;

    if ([pinch scale] > previousScale) {
        zoomLevel += estimatedDelta;
    }

    if ([pinch scale] < previousScale) {
        zoomLevel -= estimatedDelta;
    }

    previousScale = [pinch scale];

    if (zoomLevel < MIN_ZOOM_LEVEL) {
        zoomLevel = MIN_ZOOM_LEVEL;
    }

    if (zoomLevel > MAX_ZOOM_LEVEL) {
        zoomLevel = MAX_ZOOM_LEVEL;
    }

    CGPoint loc = [pinch locationInView:self];

    NSLog(@"loc: {%.1f,%.1f}, lastPinchLoc: {%.1f,%.1f}", loc.x,loc.y,lastPinchLocation.x,lastPinchLocation.y);

    //uncomment the below part to always zoom from the first zoom location.
    //if (lastPinchLocation.x != 0 && lastPinchLocation.y != 0) {
        //loc.x += lastPinchLocation.x - loc.x;
        //loc.y += lastPinchLocation.y - loc.y;
    //}

    //NSLog(@"newLastPinchLocation: {%.1f,%.1f}", loc.x,loc.y);

    lastPinchLocation = loc;

    hasBeenMoved = YES;

    if (zoomLevel != previousZoomLevel) {
        [self setNeedsDisplay];
    }
}
```

The above NSLog gives the following prints when i pinch all over the screen:

```
2012-10-16 10:15:19.357 App[2609:907] loc: {147.0,232.0}, lastPinchLoc: {0.0,0.0}
2012-10-16 10:15:19.391 App[2609:907] loc: {147.0,231.0}, lastPinchLoc: {147.0,232.0}
2012-10-16 10:15:19.436 App[2609:907] loc: {148.0,232.0}, lastPinchLoc: {147.0,231.0}
2012-10-16 10:15:19.457 App[2609:907] loc: {148.0,232.0}, lastPinchLoc: {148.0,232.0}
2012-10-16 10:15:19.474 App[2609:907] loc: {148.0,233.0}, lastPinchLoc: {148.0,232.0}
2012-10-16 10:15:19.507 App[2609:907] loc: {147.0,233.0}, lastPinchLoc: {148.0,233.0}
2012-10-16 10:15:19.573 App[2609:907] loc: {103.0,355.0}, lastPinchLoc: {147.0,233.0}
2012-10-16 10:15:20.324 App[2609:907] loc: {585.0,710.0}, lastPinchLoc: {103.0,355.0}
2012-10-16 10:15:20.340 App[2609:907] loc: {584.0,709.0}, lastPinchLoc: {585.0,710.0}
2012-10-16 10:15:20.356 App[2609:907] loc: {584.0,710.0}, lastPinchLoc: {584.0,709.0}
2012-10-16 10:15:20.374 App[2609:907] loc: {584.0,710.0}, lastPinchLoc: {584.0,710.0}
2012-10-16 10:15:20.407 App[2609:907] loc: {583.0,710.0}, lastPinchLoc: {584.0,710.0}
2012-10-16 10:15:20.456 App[2609:907] loc: {512.0,811.0}, lastPinchLoc: {583.0,710.0}
2012-10-16 10:15:21.056 App[2609:907] loc: {645.0,163.0}, lastPinchLoc: {512.0,811.0}
2012-10-16 10:15:21.090 App[2609:907] loc: {647.0,164.0}, lastPinchLoc: {645.0,163.0}
2012-10-16 10:15:21.107 App[2609:907] loc: {647.0,165.0}, lastPinchLoc: {647.0,164.0}
2012-10-16 10:15:21.156 App[2609:907] loc: {602.0,249.0}, lastPinchLoc: {647.0,165.0}
2012-10-16 10:15:21.839 App[2609:907] loc: {153.0,702.0}, lastPinchLoc: {602.0,249.0}
2012-10-16 10:15:21.856 App[2609:907] loc: {157.0,703.0}, lastPinchLoc: {153.0,702.0}
2012-10-16 10:15:21.874 App[2609:907] loc: {159.0,704.0}, lastPinchLoc: {157.0,703.0}
2012-10-16 10:15:21.890 App[2609:907] loc: {160.0,704.0}, lastPinchLoc: {159.0,704.0}
2012-10-16 10:15:21.906 App[2609:907] loc: {123.0,796.0}, lastPinchLoc: {160.0,704.0}
2012-10-16 10:15:21.923 App[2609:907] loc: {125.0,794.0}, lastPinchLoc: {123.0,796.0}
2012-10-16 10:15:22.706 App[2609:907] loc: {368.0,303.0}, lastPinchLoc: {125.0,794.0}
2012-10-16 10:15:22.723 App[2609:907] loc: {369.0,307.0}, lastPinchLoc: {368.0,303.0}
2012-10-16 10:15:22.725 App[2609:907] loc: {369.0,307.0}, lastPinchLoc: {369.0,307.0}
2012-10-16 10:15:22.739 App[2609:907] loc: {371.0,312.0}, lastPinchLoc: {369.0,307.0}
2012-10-16 10:15:22.756 App[2609:907] loc: {374.0,312.0}, lastPinchLoc: {371.0,312.0}
2012-10-16 10:15:22.773 App[2609:907] loc: {338.0,392.0}, lastPinchLoc: {374.0,312.0}
```

Just before drawing an item on the CGContext the x and y are put into this method and i draw the item on the returned location. The class variable 'zoomTouchLocation' has the same value as 'lastPinchLocation' in the above snippet.

[code snippet 2]

```
- (CGPoint)handleCoordinatesX:(float)x y:(float)y {
    x -= zoomTouchLocation.x;
    y -= zoomTouchLocation.y;

    x = x * zoomLevel;
    y = y * zoomLevel;

    x += zoomTouchLocation.x;
    y += zoomTouchLocation.y;

    return CGPointMake(x, y);
}
```

If i pinch in roughly the same location each time it will work as intended, but when i pinch all over the screen the image jumps around like crazy.

Now basically my question is if anyone can help me with this 'jumping around' problem and get the image to scale from the location i zoomed at without jumping around. If you need any more information just ask in the comments below.

(and i do know it's quite normal that the jumping occurs with my code as it is, i just can't find the way to stop it from doing that)

Comment: have you tried filtering the input values? i.e. not allow to much jumps? another question is - when it goes from 300 something to 700 something - what do you do then? can it be that you trigger on another view (i.e. a different coordinate system)?

Comment: No, im not filtering input at the moment (i'm gonna try that next week) and i'm not working on a different coordinate system. The problem is that the actual pinch gesture is on a completely different place than the previous. That is when the jumping occurs

Comment: @hims056 - Hmm you are right, that was kind of silly. Guess i'll get a cup of coffee first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to help without the whole code but you should try to set the view.layer.anchorPoint to your pinchLocation (if it's not already done).
Like this, when the transformation is done, this point doesn't move. Really useful for rotation or scaling.

Comment: I'm not using the official scaling methods that apple has provided. Before i draw something i zoom it using the method in [code snippet 2] this way it shows the network zoomed from the point of the pinch which works perfectly, but it jumps around when the user decides to pinch on different places all over the screen.

Comment: In order to debug that, you should check that your pinchLocation is never moved. A graphical way to do that would be to display a red button on your layer and check if it moves.

Comment: I was working in the wrong coordinate system. Your comment got me looking in the correct place, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your zoom deltas and coordinates should be tracked and/or reset during discrete events. That is, you need to be aware of and use the `UIPinchGestureRecognizer.state` to determine where your tracking logic and deltas are to be reset, and when to update the coordinates you track for your zoom position.

---

One basic illustration of this comes from the Touches sample:

```
- (void)scalePiece:(UIPinchGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer
{
    [self adjustAnchorPointForGestureRecognizer:gestureRecognizer];

    if ([gestureRecognizer state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan || [gestureRecognizer state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged) {
        [gestureRecognizer view].transform = CGAffineTransformScale([[gestureRecognizer view] transform], [gestureRecognizer scale], [gestureRecognizer scale]);
        [gestureRecognizer setScale:1];
    }
}
```